# Share text on Facebook using sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I am working on an android app in which  I am sharing content on facebook. I am able to share link, image. But i am unable to  send when i only post text on facebook. I did not get any thing. I am using following code for share on facebook.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", webPageContent);
bundle.putString("message", webPageContent);
FeedDialogBuilder feedDialog = new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(FacebookShareActivity.this,Session.getActiveSession(),bundle)
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (error == null) {
                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                // and the post Id.
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookShareActivity.this, "Posted story, id: "+postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    });

feedDialog.build().show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the docs for the feed dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

As you can see, there's no message property. This is because prefilling the status update for the user is against platform policies.